# Multiple ListForm WebParts on single DispForm.aspx

Tags: display-form, list-form-web-part

Has anybody an idea of how I could achieve this? In my test scenario I'm displaying two ListForm WebParts, but only one shows data. I think the context is wrong / missing for the second one.

Comment: SharePoint 2010 Server Enterprise Edition

Answer (score 1):

In 2010 you used to be able to add a child list view which was automatically related to the item you were looking at.

There seems to be a problem with this in 2013.

Comment: I'm using 2010.

Comment: If you CTRL-click on your list to display your item you can then edit the page in the browser.  Select the existing web part on the page and an option will appear in the ribbon to add a child web part.

Comment: I need a second ListForm WebPart(Editform,Displayform) that points to an item in a second list, not list view.

Comment: Ah - I saw DispForm.aspx in the title of your post and assumed this was what you wanted.  I have not tried it but think you should be able to create a custom ASPX page with 2 custom forms on it - but I am not sure this would work in a DispForm.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, no it doesn't work as expected.